# AWS cloudwatch cron expression issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create a Cloudwatch rule using Python and boto. We need to run this in a 5 min interval. But we get the following error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutRule operation: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid.

```py
cw_client.put_rule(
   Name= "lambda-kickoff",
   ScheduleExpression = cron_exp,
   # ScheduleExpression="cron(0/5 * * * ? *)",
   State='ENABLED',
   Description= "cw rule 1",
)
```

cron_exp value is: cron(19 10 30 4 FRI 2021)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutRule operation: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid.

Comment: Is `cron_exp` actually a string? Since the code is missing it is not clear but could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your cron expression is wrong because either day of month or day of the week must be a questionmark, according to the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents-expressions.html).

> One of the day-of-month or day-of-week values must be a question mark (?).

Answer (score 0):

You can use both cron and rate expression:

```
cron_exp = 'cron(*/5 * * * ? *)' # every 5 minute using cron expression

rate_exp = 'rate(5 minute)' # every 5 minute using rate expression
```

Comment: aws eventbridge support both cron and rate expression